# show product label on sale products

Tags: product, sales-order, sales, labels

How to show product label sale only on products that are on sale?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following show sale label

```
<?php
$_finalPrice =$_product->getFinalPrice(); 
$_price =$_product->getPrice();
if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
   On Sale

<?php endif; ?>
```